# Access Query Criteria

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, where-clause

I need the syntax for a Microsoft Access Query Criteria that states that

```
If TblA.ColA = TblB.ColA And
   TblA.ColB = TblB.ColB And
   TblB.ColC = QueryFieldA And
   TblB.ColD = QueryFieldB
Then 
    give me the number in TblB.Col E
End If
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the two tables have to be joined on `ColA` and `ColB` (difficult to say without knowing the structure of your tables).

```sql
SELECT TblB.ColE
FROM
    TblA
    INNER JOIN TblB
        ON TblA.ColA = TblB.ColA AND
           TblA.ColB = TblB.ColB 
WHERE
    TblB.ColC = QueryFieldA AND
    TblB.ColD = QueryFieldB
```